# Can't put object on top of another object with OverlayLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, overlay

I'm trying to build a tower defense game. Now I'd completed class Map (maps with a path for monster to pass) and class Creep (monster passing the map).

The creep object shall be on top of the map object. But the creep object is now moving behind the map and completely invisible. I'd tried to alter arguments of g.fillOval() in paintComponent() of class Creep and I'm sure that the creep is moving behind.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST_MAP");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled(){
                return false;
            }
        };
        LayoutManager overlay = new OverlayLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(overlay);
        Map testMap = new Map();
        panel.add(testMap);
        Creep red = new Creep(testMap);
        panel.add(red);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class Map extends JComponent
{
    static final int largeGrid = 50;
    int[][] path = new int[2][];

    public Map()
    {
        path[0] = new int[] {0, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7};
        path[1] = new int[] {1, 1, 6, 6, 2, 2};
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        for(int i = 0; i < 6 - 1; i++)
        {
            if(path[0][i] == path[0][i + 1]) //Vertical
                g.fillRect(
                Math.min(path[0][i], path[0][i + 1]) * largeGrid - largeGrid / 2, 
                Math.min(path[1][i], path[1][i + 1]) * largeGrid - largeGrid / 2, 
                largeGrid, 
                Math.abs(line(i)[2] - line(i)[1]) * largeGrid + largeGrid);
            else //Horizontal
                g.fillRect(
                Math.min(path[0][i], path[0][i + 1]) * largeGrid - largeGrid / 2, 
                Math.min(path[1][i], path[1][i + 1]) * largeGrid - largeGrid / 2, 
                Math.abs(line(i)[2] - line(i)[1]) * largeGrid + largeGrid, 
                largeGrid);
        }
    }

    public int[] line(int i)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[3];
        if(path[0][i] == path[0][i + 1])
        {
            temp[0] = path[0][i]; //Longitudinal coordinate
            temp[1] = path[1][i];
            temp[2] = path[1][i + 1];
        } else
        {
            temp[0] = path[1][i];
            temp[1] = path[0][i];
            temp[2] = path[0][i + 1];
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

class Creep extends JComponent implements Runnable
{
    public static final int diameter = 30;
    int hp, speed, posX, posY;
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    Map m;

    public Creep(Map m)
    {
        this.m = m;
        posX = m.path[0][0] * Map.largeGrid;
        posY = m.path[1][0] * Map.largeGrid;
        t.start();
    }

    public Creep(int hp, int speed, Map m)
    {
        this(m);
        this.hp = hp;
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(posX - diameter / 2, posY - diameter / 2, diameter, diameter);
    }

    public void walk() throws InterruptedException
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m.path[0].length - 1; i++)
        {
            if(m.path[0][i] == m.path[0][i + 1]) //Vertical
            {
                while(posY != m.path[1][i + 1] * Map.largeGrid)
                {
                    if(m.path[1][i] < m.path[1][i + 1])
                        posY++;
                    else
                        posY--;
                    repaint();
                    t.sleep(5);
                }
            } else //Horizontal
            {
                while(posX != m.path[0][i + 1] * Map.largeGrid)
                {
                    if(m.path[0][i] < m.path[0][i + 1])
                        posX++;
                    else
                        posX--;
                    repaint();
                    t.sleep(5);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            walk();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel Can you teach me how to move Creep on top of Map? I've been trying for days...